# Openshift mysql write access from php

Tags: php, mysql, permissions, openshift

I have an issue with my mysql database that I can't resolve : I have a scalable application with mysql and php. I can access the database but I can only read ('SELECT') the data but I don't seem to have the permission to write ('INSERT INTO...').

Here is the php file for SELECT command which is working :

```
<?php
$cnx = mysql_connect("domain:port","username","password");
$db= mysql_select_db( "application_name" );
$username = $_POST['username'];
$password = $_POST['password'];
$sql = "SELECT * FROM `User` where `userName`='$username' AND `password`='$password'";
$requete = mysql_query($sql ,$cnx);

if(mysql_num_fields($requete)==0){
  echo "0";
}
else {
$result = mysql_fetch_assoc( $requete );
    echo $result["userKey"];
}?>
```

And the php file for INSERT INTO command which is not working :

```
<?php
$con=mysql_connect("domain:port","username","password","application_name");
$username = $_POST['username'];
$password = $_POST['password'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$sql="INSERT INTO User(userName,emailAdress,password) VALUES ('$username','$email','$password')";
if (mysqli_query($con,$sql))
{
  echo "0";
}
?>
```

Thanks for your help !

Comment: What errors are you getting?

Comment: Please list the actual errors that you are getting from the code that you believe is NOT working correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Install PHPMyAdmin, and then create a new schema. You should be able to carry out all usual executions into that schema you created.

Alternatively, SSH into your gear, type 'mysql'. This will give you access to the database. Create a schema from there and then in your PHP script, when you connect to the db, specify the schema as the one you created.